# Is there a way to change the color of a bar graph based on the data provided from a csv file, using the matplotlib/pandas module in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am looking to change the color of each individual bar in this graph using matplotlib. I just can not seem to figure it out. I have tried using an if/elif/else statement to check the values, but this was unsuccessful. I then tried a for loop and nested the if statements inside of that, but this was unsuccessful as well.
The code I have is attached below. (My apologies if it is a mess, or perhaps right in front of my face. I am a student in university, so I am still learning!)

Code:

```
import string
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_data(filename, horizontal, vertical):
    graph_colors = {'limegreen':'#CCFF33',
                    'lightgreen':'#9ef01a',
                    'green':'#70e000',
                    'darkgreen':'#38b000',
                    'darkergreen':'#008000',
                    'darkestgreen':'#007200'}
    
    letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
    numbers = list(range(0,26))
    fields = dict(zip(letters, numbers))

    datafile = pd.read_csv(filename)
    cols = list(datafile.columns)
    title = filename[:-4]
    x_axis = cols[fields[horizontal]]
    y_axis = cols[fields[vertical]]
    datafile = datafile.sort_values(y_axis)

    color_of_graph = 'blue'
    for row in datafile:
        if '31' in row:
            color_of_graph = graph_colors['darkestgreen']
    
    datafile.plot(title=title, legend=False, x=x_axis, y=y_axis, kind='bar', color=color_of_graph)
    plt.xlabel(x_axis)
    plt.ylabel(y_axis)
    plt.show()
plot_data("my_file", 'A', 'B')` # A is column a in csv file, B is column b in csv file
```

Column B (or the plot_data function's third parameter) contains the data that would change the color.

The for loop I tried is:

```
color_of_graph = 'blue'
for row in datafile:
    if '31' in row:
        color_of_graph = graph_colors['darkestgreen']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with:

```
for row in datafile:
    ...
```

Is that `for x in pandas.df` iterates over column names. So you are basically checking if `"31"` is in the name of each column.

If you want to change the color based on 3rd argument and value in that column you should try:

```
if 31 in datafile[vertical].values:
    color_of_graph = graph_colors["darkestgreen"]
```